# When I type `route -n` into the Mac terminal, why doesn't it show a routing table?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, networking, tcp

I read in "TCP/IP Network Administration" by O'Reilly, 2002, that typing the `route -n` command should bring up a routing table.

When I typed it into the terminal on a Mac, it returned the following:

`usage: route [-dnqtv] command [[modifiers] args]`

What is the correct command to use to see the routing table in my terminal?

Comment: That book is about linux; the commands are unlikely to be the same on BSD-pedigree Mac OS X.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

On Mac OS X you can use [`netstat(1)`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/netstat/).  In your case, `netstat -nr`, probably.

Comment: Where does this command come from? or Where is the system manual that I can look for? any help is appreciate

Comment: Come from? It's included with macOS. The man page is linked in my answer.